# Convert Sharepoint webpart 2013 to 32 bit version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, excel

Are there any ways to convert the visual webpart to 32 bit version. I have target in the property project c#, but I couldn't add the webpart to page.

What I meant is in my case: I open excel file by connection string

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;Data Source= " + filePath +
>   ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\""

But it raised the error on the step open connection. I have aleady installed the Access Database Engine distribution 2010 X64 on the server and the client also.

Answer (score 0):

No, web part deployed to SharePoint has to be compiled in 64-bit.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710798/microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported-in-32-bit-process-please-verify-that-you